# replacing wpf image source on the fly

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using an Image in xaml like below,

```
<Image x:Name="JustMyImage" Width="635" Height="120" Canvas.Left="-19" Canvas.Top="-19" Source="../images/UnCategorized/Anywhere.png"/>
```

If i want to dynamically change the image source i need to do the following code

```
 BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.UriSource = new Uri(".\images\panel.PNG", UriKind.Relative);
            bi.EndInit();

            this.JustMyImage.Source = bi;
```

Is there a straight forward 'one line' method to replace the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
 JustMyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(".\images\panel.PNG"))
```

Comment: It will work exactly like that, without BeginInit and EndInit. Otherwise the constructor with Uri parameter wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @Vale: It will work if you use parameterized constructor of BitmapImage....For more info, you can see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=vs.95)#1

Comment: Yes, in theory. But I couldn't make it work without the init part

Comment: @Vale You could ask a question here and try to get help with that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a BitmapImage tag in your Resources and reference it (I think StaticResource will work, otherwise use DynamicResource).

Reference this BitmapImage from your "JustMyImage". When you update the URI of your BitmapImage, "JustMyImage" should reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

I use Converter to solve this problem:

```
public class KepPathKonverter : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        BitmapImage o;
        try
        {
            o = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"{Main.baseDir}\\{value}"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            o = new BitmapImage();
        }
        return o;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```